# Java - class objects used instead of prototyping?

Tags: java, class, object, prototype, clone

I read that you can use class objects instead of using prototype with cloning. But I don't understand what it mean to use class objects instead of that? Can anyone give an example if someone understand what would mean to use class objects instead of prototype pattern?..

Comment: are we talking about Java or JavaScript here?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: Do you have a link to the article that you read? Prototyping is a solution when creating an object hierarchy and the associated operations is either expensive or not feasible. Take the example of a game state - Let us say you played for 2 hours and saved the state. When you resume it is easier to clone the previously saved state than run all the operations worth 2 hours. So a reference to what you read might help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Java 5, `java.lang.Class` is generic on the type of itself. This permits the class to create its instances in a type-safe way.

When you use a prototype with cloning, you do something like this:

```
interface Calculator {
    void setA(int a);
    void setB(int b);
    int compute();
    Calculator copy();
}
class Adder implements Calculator {
    private int a,b;
    public void setA(int a) {this.a=a;}
    public void setB(int b) {this.b=b;}
    public int compute() {return a+b;}
    public Calculator copy() {
        Adder res = new Adder();
        res.a = a;
        res.b = b;
        return res;
    }
}
class Multiplier implements Calculator {
    private int a,b;
    public void setA(int a) {this.a=a;}
    public void setB(int b) {this.b=b;}
    public int compute() {return a*b;}
    public Calculator copy() {
        Multiplier res = new Multiplier();
        res.a = a;
        res.b = b;
        return res;
    }
}
class Test {
    static void computeWithPrototype(Calculator proto) {
         Calculator calc = proto.copy();
         calc.setA(123);
         calc.setB(321);
         System.out.println(calc.compute());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        computeWithPrototype(new Adder());
        computeWithPrototype(new Multiplier());
    }
}
```

[Demo of the above approach on ideone](http://ideone.com/0as5bS).

You can re-write it with a `Class<T>` instead of a `copy` method, like this:

```
interface Calculator {
    void setA(int a);
    void setB(int b);
    int compute();
}
class Adder implements Calculator {
    private int a,b;
    public void setA(int a) {this.a=a;}
    public void setB(int b) {this.b=b;}
    public int compute() {return a+b;}
}
class Multiplier implements Calculator {
    private int a,b;
    public void setA(int a) {this.a=a;}
    public void setB(int b) {this.b=b;}
    public int compute() {return a*b;}
}
class Test {
    static <T extends Calculator> void computeWithClass(Class<T> calcClass)
    throws Exception {
         Calculator calc = calcClass.newInstance();
         calc.setA(123);
         calc.setB(321);
         System.out.println(calc.compute());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        computeWithClass(Adder.class);
        computeWithClass(Multiplier.class);
    }
}
```

[Demo of the second approach on ideone.](http://ideone.com/kQDFaE)

Answer (score 0):

In java when you create a object it have a reference memory. So when you try to assign that object to a variable you pass a reference memory.

Example :

```
Person a = new Person(); a.setName("Person abc");
Person b = a; b.setName("Person yzw"); 
System.out.print(a.getName());
System.out.print(b.getName());
```

For this reason when you modify a attribute that belong at this memory reference you modify both.
It going to print : "yzw yzw";

So if you don't want that it occurs, so use Cloneable interface :

```
public class Person implements Cloneable{

    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

So when you call a clone() method you will have a two different object. 
Example:

```
Person a = new Person();
a.setName("Person abc");
Person b = (Person)a.clone(); 
System.out.print(a.getName());
System.out.print(b.getName());
```

It going to print : "abc yzw";